# Linked List with String

Tags: c++, struct

I am doing a project for a programming subject. They ask to save a project in a linked list. Here you have my Struct:

```
typedef struct dados {

    int ID;

    string title;

    char institution[150];

    char investigator[150];

    string keywords[5];

    float money;

    struct dados *next; //pointer to next nodule

}No;
```

This is the 2nd phase of the project, the first one was using a simple array of structs, but this phase they want the same but with a linked list.

I have a function that I use to insert data in a struct. The function ask for an input and I save the data in the struct.

The insertion function:

```
No * insertBegin(No * head){

    No * newNode;

    newNode= (No *)malloc(sizeof(No));

    cout << endl << "Qual e o titulo do projeto?" << endl << endl;

    getline(cin, newNode->titulo)

    //More data like this, on the end:

    newNode->next= head;
}
```

To save a string for title in the first phase I was using this:

```
getline(cin, no.title);
```

I want to do the same for the second phase and I did:

```
getline(cin, no->title);
```

But it gives this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00E14E96 in Aplicacao.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

I don´t know what to do. Can you help me please?

Thanks a million.

Comment: `0xCDCDCDCD` = uninitialized heap memory.

Comment: Can you be more specifically? I am new with C/C++. By the way thanks to answer me.

Comment: Share your code for insertion

Comment: It means the pointer you are using has not been initialized. I suspect it would be a dados*.

Comment: Did you remember to use `new` to create a new node instance for your node pointer to reference?

Comment: You need to show the code that you add nodes.

Comment: What is `No` ? is it not `dados` ?

Comment: It's a more simple way to call the struct.

Comment: I did initialized the pointer with this `No * newNode;`

Comment: @Ben there is an malloc under that line

Comment: Post your actual full code, the way it is in your editor. Give us english names in code comments if you feel the need to clarify.

We can help you better if we see what you're actually compiling.

Comment: no->title is probably just a pointer that needs memory associated with it.  If title is only a pointer and not an array/string, the cin could cause the above condition.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new`. `malloc`does not construct class instances.

Comment: That is the problem `newNode= (No *)malloc(sizeof(No));` does not initialize the strings since the constructors are not called. So when you attempt to use the uninitialized string you dereference an uninitialized pointer internal to the implementation of std::string. As @molbdnilo and others said use new instead of malloc with c++.

Comment: Thank you ALL. The problem is solved. I use `No * newNode = new No` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you cannot use malloc to create an instance of the "No" struct because malloc will not call the constructor of the string.  So the function becomes:

```
No * insertBegin(No * head){
    No * newNode;

    //newNode= (No *)malloc(sizeof(No));
    newNode = new No();

    cout << endl << "Qual e o titulo do projeto?" << endl << endl;

    getline(cin, newNode->titulo)

    //More data like this, on the end:

    newNode->next= head;
}
```

Be aware that you should not free() on the object either.  Instead, use the [delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/) keyword.